# Remove a word and exactly one word before it

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I need to remove exactly one word before a given word, as well as the given word, in R.
The strings are:

```
string <- c('first local hospital orlando', 'state hospital claifornia', 'state hospital orlando')
```

I know how to delete everything before the word hospital:

```
univ_reg$col3 <- str_replace_all(univ_reg$col3, ".*hospital", "")
```

But I need to delete exactly one word and the word hospital. I cannot create a list of words that go before hospital because the list will be too big, so I need to use regex. I want it to look like:

```
string_new <- c('first orlando', 'claifornia', 'orlando')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gsub()` as follows:

```
gsub("\\b\\w+\\s+hospital\\b\\s+", "", string)
# [1] "first orlando" "claifornia"    "orlando"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your own attempt uses `stringr`, here's a `stringr` solution:

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(string, "\\b\\w+ hospital ", "")
```

`str_replace_all` is not needed as you seem to have just one match per string; for that purpose `str_replace` is sufficient (as is, by the way, `sub`; `gsub` is warranted if you expect more than one match per string).